# Accessing a web page that has SSO/SAML and 2FA enabled from Powershell

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, saml

We have a remotely-hosted website that uses our company's SSO sign-on via SAML, with two factor authentication (2FA) enabled. I would like to be able to use a local Jenkins agent.jar file to access this webpage via the usual https port (443) to download the .jnlp configuration to then access it via another port which I can configure from Jenkins. That's the background.

To do the first part, I need to be able to authorise the agent.jar file to connect to the website on port 443. The closest I've got so far is the following Powershell script:

```
# Install Azure PowerShell module if not already installed
# Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

# Import the Az module
Import-Module Az

# Sign in interactively
Connect-AzAccount

# Get the access token
$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com").Token
echo $accessToken

# Use the access token to make requests
Invoke-WebRequest "https://our.website" -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" }
```

This brings up the 2FA login screen, which appears to work to log me in as I get an access token. However when I then attempt to access our.website (not our real address, obviously!), I still get the 200 "Sign into  your account" response.

Is anyone able to help with this? I've searched and trawled everywhere and there doesn't seem to be an answer that works. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You won't be able to complete the 2FA part from powershell. No way, and this is by design. Typically, for this kind of a thing a web service will also have to support OAuth (or worse: legacy basic auth), or using API keys... at least for certain users. Or, for some services, the MFA enforcement can be turned off for specific service accounts (which is part of why service account credentials need to be regularly rotated, even if normal user credentials do not).

Comment: SAML is the body of a SOAP.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare a working request with a different tool and the powershell request.  Once you have a connection the request is the same no matter what language is used.

Comment: Thanks - I'm happy to do the 2FA part manually, as that will only be needed once per starting of the service (plus it's a sensible security measure anyway). So my frustration/challenge is that even having done that part, which I thought would have resulted in a suitable access token being available, the web request using that token is then rejected.